# How to open NERDTree without focusing it

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to execute (via a keymap), while in the current buffer: NERDTreeCWD and NERDTreeFind. So I would do:

```
map <F8> :ProjectRootExe NERDTreeCWD<CR>:NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

The problem is, that NERDTreeCWD focues the NERDTree, and makes the "NERDTreeFind" not work.

So I need to open the NERDTree without focusing it. My Idea would be to call `:b#` to jump to the last buffer:

```
map <F8> :ProjectRootExe NERDTreeCWD<CR>:b#<CR>:NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

Unfortunately it seems that `:b#` does not work, whole in the NERDTree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go back to the previous window with `<C-w>p`; in a command-line, the equivalent `:wincmd p` comes handy. With this, you can write the entire mapping as  a single command-line:

```
nnoremap <F8> :ProjectRootExe NERDTreeCWD<Bar>wincmd p<Bar>NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

<sup>[You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.</sup>